# In SQL, how do I coalesce the first value of 3 columns that is 10 characters long

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I am trying to only select one column from 3 distinct phone number columns, and I would prefer to have the column with the longest phone number (some don't have area codes). Currently, I have coalesced the 3 columns as some are also null, with a preference on cell phone.

Ex.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons
(
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NULL
   ,cell_number VARCHAR(20) NULL
   ,home_number VARCHAR(20) NULL
   ,work_number VARCHAR(20) NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Persons
(
    first_name
   ,cell_number
   ,home_number
   ,work_number
)
VALUES
    ( 'Dave' -- first_name - varchar(100)
     ,'4567891' -- cell_number - varchar(20)
     ,'1234567891' -- home_number - varchar(20)
     ,NULL -- work_number - varchar(20)
    )
,
    ( 'Ron' -- first_name - varchar(100)
     ,'1234567891' -- cell_number - varchar(20)
     ,NULL -- home_number - varchar(20)
     ,NULL -- work_number - varchar(20)
    )
,
    ( 'Yitzhak' -- first_name - varchar(100)
     ,'123' -- cell_number - varchar(20)
     ,NULL -- home_number - varchar(20)
     ,'1234567891' -- work_number - varchar(20)
    );
```

What I've tried :

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
    COALESCE(cell_number, home_number, work_number)
FROM Persons ORDER BY LEN(cell_number),LEN(home_number),LEN(work_number) DESC;
```

I would prefer to just have the first number that is 10 characters long or the longest of the 3 columns, I can only have one column returned. Bonus points if it can keep a preference of cell_number , but not required.

@@version : Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 18363: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: This doesn't sound like you want `COALESCE`, which returns the first non-`NULL` parameter. It doesn't care about string length.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, added more of this info.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression.  However, `outer apply` is simpler than a big case expression -- and generalizes to more phone numbers much more easily:

```
select p.*, v.phone
from persons p outer apply
     (select top (1) v.phone
      from (values (cell_number, 1), (home_number, 2), (work_number, 2)
           ) v(phone, priority)
      where v.phone is not null
      order by len(v.phone) desc, priority
     ) v;
```

Comment: Might as well add the "bonus if it can keep a preference of cell_number" bit with an explicit 2 column values constructor with a tiebreaker to order by, in case they want to have more control over the priorities in future

Comment: @allmhuran . . . That is actually easy.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , can this be applied to a query that is unioned? Otherwise, this is exactly what I was after, Thanks!

Comment: @BenRaymond . . . You might want to put the "union" portion in a CTE and just use a CTE for `persons`.